# ModelMapper integration with Jooq Record

Tags: java, jooq, modelmapper

===== **POJO** =====

```
// Employee POJO
     @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
     @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.class)
     public class Employee implements Serializable {
       private Integer id;
       private String name;
       private Integer companyId;
       // assume getters ,setters and serializable implementations.
     }
// Company POJO
     @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
     @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.class)
     public class Company implements Serializable {
       private Integer id;
       private String name;
       // assume getters ,setters and serializable implementations.
     }

// EmployeeVO POJO
     @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
     @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.class)
     public class EmployeeVO implements Serializable {
       private Employee employee;
       private Company company;

       // assume getters ,setters and serializable implementations.
     }
```

===== **My DAO layer class** =====

```
public List<EmployeeVO> getEmployees(){     
    // configuring model mapper.
       ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
       modelMapper.getConfiguration()
                  .addValueReader(new RecordValueReader())
              .setSourceNameTokenizer(NameTokenizers.UNDERSCORE);

    //property map configuration.
      PropertyMap<Record, EmployeeVO> employeeVOMap = new PropertyMap<Record, EmployeeVO>() {
       protected void configure() {
          map().getEmployee().setName(this.<String>source("name"));
          map().getEmployee()..setId(this.<Integer>source("id"));
          map().getCompany().setName(this.<String>source("comp_name"));
          map().getCompany().setId(this.<String>source("comp_id"));
        }
     };
    // TypeMap config
    modelMapper.createTypeMap(Record.class, EmployeeVO.class);
    // adding employeeVOMap .
    modelMapper.addMappings(employeeVOMap);         

// JOOQ query  
    List<Field<?>> fields = Lists.newArrayList();  
    //  fields includes, id, name, comp_name, comp_id

    SelectJoinStep query = select(dslContext, fields).from(EMPLOYEE)
                                       .join(COMPANY)
                                       .on(COMPANY.ID.equal(EMPLOYEE.COMPANY_ID));    
        Result<Record> records = query.fetch();

    Record record = null;
        Iterator<Record> it = records.iterator();
        List<EmployeeVO> employeeList=  Lists.newArrayList();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            record = it.next();

            EmployeeVO employeeVOObj =
                    modelMapper.map(record, EmployeeVO.class);
            employeeList.add(employeeVOObj);
        }
    return employeeList;    
}
```

===== **Error log** =====

1) Error `mapping org.jooq.impl.RecordImpl to com.myportal.bingo.db.model.EmployeeVO`
    1 error] with root cause
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

**Note:** 
ModelMapper throws the above exception when it reaches below method.

`private void matchSource(TypeInfo<?> sourceTypeInfo, Mutator destinationMutator)` 
in `ImplicitMappingBuilder.java`

```
sourceTypeInfo.getAccessors() is null.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, or at least which looked the same. (You can move directly to my solution in the last paragraph.) Lots of debugging have shown the following:

if accessors on that line (mentioned in your question) are null, then `accessors = PropertyInfoSetResolver.resolveAccessors(source, type, configuration)` line in TypeInfoImpl class is executed, and the reason of exception in my case was this call:

`valueReader.get(source, memberName)` at the following piece of code at 'resolveAccessors' method in the PropertyInfoSetResolver class:

```
if (valueReader == null)
  resolveProperties(type, true, configuration, accessors);
else {
  NameTransformer nameTransformer = configuration.getSourceNameTransformer();
  for (String memberName : valueReader.memberNames(source))
    accessors.put(nameTransformer.transform(memberName, NameableType.GENERIC),
        new ValueReaderPropertyInfo(valueReader, valueReader.get(source, memberName),
            memberName));
```

which ends up in `source.getValue(memberName.toUpperCase())`, where `source` is JOOQ's Record; InvoiceRecord in my case. And - tada - for some reason `invoice.getValue("INVOICE_ID")` ends up in the exception (no such field and therefore `indexOf` returns `-1` which causes the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException), while `invoice.getValue("invoice_id")` is totally fine.

So `else` condition (the same piece of code above) wasn't the right way to execute the code, and `if` case turned out to be ok.

So that's what helped me in my particular case: removing of the row `modelMapper.getConfiguration().addValueReader(new RecordValueReader())`. Hope this will help you too.

Comment: I removed the line but no luck.

Comment: Is the line `modelMapper.getConfiguration().setSourceNameTokenizer(NameTokenizers.UNDERSCORE);` still present in your code?
Well, anyway, good luck!

Comment: no, I commented-out that and executed it. BTW, I am trying to get all the fields from two different tables using joins. so its not just on table record.

Comment: And I think the problem is(same as you explained), RecordValueReader is trying to convert the source(Jooq record) member names to upper case, but in my case at-least, I am getting the member names as lower case. Any way that we fix this without ignoring RecordValueReader as it plays the role in converting the jooq record?

Comment: "Any way that we fix this without ignoring RecordValueReader as it plays the role in converting the jooq record?" - you're right, it should matter, but the only solution I can see ATM is to edit the RecordValueReader class (e.g. remove that `toUpperCase()` fragment), fortunately it's a small class, only 36 lines.

Comment: Yes, I did that I now I am getting only the string data, matching failed in ImplicitMappingBuilder -> matchSource(), don't understand how it just find the matching for the string data. any idea?